# SQL View with LIKE?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, where-clause, sql-like

I get data from 3 tables into a view:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.A.[key] DESC) AS ID, 
    dbo.A.[key], dbo.B.ARBPL, 
    dbo.A.[rssi_mittelwert (dBm)], dbo.A.[rssi_varianz (dBm)], 
    dbo.A.[rssi_standardabweichung (dBm)], 
    dbo.A.[snr_mittelwert (dB)], dbo.A.[snr_varianz (dB)], 
    dbo.A.[snr_standardabweichung (dB)], 
    dbo.A.Zeitstempel
FROM     
    dbo.C 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.B ON dbo.C.LastKnownRelation = dbo.B.[Arbeitsplatz Alias] 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    dbo.A ON dbo.C.SwitchId = dbo.A.[key]
WHERE  
    (dbo.C.Active = 1) AND (dbo.B.ARBPL IS NOT NULL)
```

My question is: how can I make a `LIKE` there, which means, its like this:

```
WHERE dbo.C.LastKnownRelation LIKE '%dbo.B.[Arbeitsplatz Alias]%'
```

so if `Arbeitsplatz Alias = Football AUS/ES` and my `LastKnownRelation = Football AUS`, it should return the result of the ARBPL because the `LIKE` is true.

Comment: I have removed the tag [tag:mysql], as this is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: FYI, [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and is best avoided. Stick to aliasing your objects and qualifying the column names with those aliases. I also strongly recommend you don't use names that don't require delimit identification as well. "Nice", user friendly names are something that should be defined in the presentation layer.

Comment: As for the question, aren't you just after `LIKE '%' + B.[Arbeitsplatz Alias] + '%'`? SQL isn't a scripting language, you can't reference an object in a literal string and expect SQL to inject its value into said string.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to filter because the view "hides" the tables that make it up. If you want to apply a filter like that, you must return the value in the view.